# load api before dependency injection in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want an api to return an **Object** before injection of module take place in angular.js

Basically the **Object** tells angular which module should be injected or not

**Api Before injection**!!

Answer (score 0):

you can make and `$factory` and use it in `run()` phase or `$provider` for it and use it in `config()` phase